# force python pyside splitter to start window center

Tags: python, pyside

How can I force the splitter to be positioned in the center of the window at the start? As you can see in the code below it favors the right side because of the  button being small. however I would like to have the splitter always appear in the middle of the window as shown in image two.

**Current**

[image]

**Goal**

[image]

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        # formatting
        self.resize(550, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Cameras")

        # widgets
        self.ListA = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.ListB = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.Button = QtGui.QPushButton()

        # layout Splitter
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)

        self.leftPanel = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        # self.leftPanel.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.leftPanelLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.leftPanel)
        self.leftPanelLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.leftPanelLayout.addWidget(self.ListA)

        self.rightPanel = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        # self.rightPanel.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.rightPanelLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.rightPanel)
        self.rightPanelLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.rightPanelLayout.addWidget(self.Button)

        self.splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.leftPanel)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.rightPanel)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.splitter)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QSplitter')
        self.show()

    def onChanged(self, text):

        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()        


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bam! got it.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        # formatting
        self.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.setWindowTitle("Cameras")

        # widgets
        self.ListA = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.ListB = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.Button = QtGui.QPushButton()

        # layout Splitter
        # QHBoxLayout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)

        self.leftPanel = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        # self.leftPanel.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.leftPanelLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.leftPanel)
        self.leftPanelLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.leftPanelLayout.addWidget(self.ListA)

        self.rightPanel = QtGui.QFrame(self)
        # self.rightPanel.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.rightPanelLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.rightPanel)
        self.rightPanelLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.rightPanelLayout.addWidget(self.Button)

        self.splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.leftPanel)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.rightPanel)
        self.splitter.setCollapsible(0,False)
        self.splitter.setCollapsible(1,False)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.splitter,0,0)

        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QSplitter')
        self.show()

        self.set_panel_sizes(self.splitter)


    def onChanged(self, text):

        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()      

    def set_panel_sizes(self, ctrl):
        width = ctrl.frameSize().width() / 2.0
        ctrl.setSizes( [width,width] )  


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```